# How to change Maven local repository in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm importing a multiple-module Maven project from the root directory on a shared drive on another server A. On server A, `mvn install` will run successfully, and Maven is set up properly with `repository/` and `settings.xml` in `/home/user/.m2`.

However, after I imported the project into Eclipse (STS actually) on my workstation PC, I can't get `mvn build` (I have the m2e plugin installed) to run, mostly due to missing dependencies from other modules. I realized that Eclipse is using `settings.xml` and `repository/` on my workstation PC, so there won't be any module build installed in the .m2 cache.

I'm trying to modify Maven to use the .m2 directory on server A. I can only set settings.xml to the one on server A, but I cannot change the local repository. The only option I have is to "re-index".

Is there a way to change the local repository to the one on server A, or is there a better way to have code on one server, and edit/build/test on Tomcat on another PC?

[image]

Answer (score 52):

location can be specified in Maven->Installation -> Global Settings: settings.xml

[image]

Comment: ... and in settings.xml must be changed  <localRepository> to point to your local repository.

Comment: I have no "global settings from installation directory" in just installed eclipse mars

Comment: @Wooff, me neither (in Mars).

Comment: me too. An update is needed to this answer for the newer versions of Eclipse.

Answer (score 17):

In general, these answer the question:  How to change your user settings file?  But the question I wanted answered was how to change my local maven repository location.  The answer is that you have to edit *settings.xml*.  If the file does not exist, you have to create it.  You set or change the location of the file at **Window > Preferences > Maven > User Settings**.  It's the **User Settings** entry at

[image: Maven User Settings dialog]

It's the second file input; the first with information in it.

If it's not clear, `[redacted]` should be replaced with the local file path to your .m2 folder.

If you click the "open file" link, it opens the *settings.xml* file for editing in Eclipse.

If you have no *settings.xml* file yet, the following will set the local repository to the Windows 10 default value for a user named mdfst13:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                              https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <localRepository>C:\Users\mdfst13\.m2\repository</localRepository>
</settings>
```

You should set this to a value appropriate to your system.  I haven't tested it, but I suspect that in Linux, the default value would be `/home/mdfst13/.m2/repository`.  And of course, you probably don't want to set it to the default value.  If you are reading this, you probably want to set it to some other value.  You could just delete it if you wanted the default.

Credit to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235374/how-to-change-maven-local-repository-in-eclipse#comment18579976_10238586) by [@ejaenv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/599971/ejaenv) for the name of the element in the settings file:  `<localRepository>`.  See [Maven — Settings Reference](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) for more information.

Credit to [@Ajinkya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52252903/6660678) for specifying the location of the User Settings value in Eclipse Photon.

If you already have a settings.xml file, you should merge this into your existing file.  I.e. `<settings` and `<localRepository>` should only appear once in the file, and you probably want to retain any settings already there.  Or to say that another way, edit any existing local repository entry if it exists or just add that line to the file if it doesn't.

I had to restart Eclipse for it to load data into the new repository.  Neither "Update Settings" nor "Reindex" was sufficient.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was trying to do.  Just wanted to add a note that I had to restart Eclipse AND right-click on the project and select Maven > Update Project in order to clear all of the errors

Answer (score 15):

In newer versions of Eclipse the global configuration file can be set in

Windows > Preferences > Maven > User Settings > Global Settings

*Don't beat me why global settings can be configured in user settings... Probably because of the same reason why you need to press "Start" to shutdown your PC on Windows...* :D

Answer (score 1):

In **Eclipse Photon** navigate to ***Windows > Preferences > Maven > User Settings > User Setting***

For "User settings" Browse to the settings.xml of the maven. ex. in my case maven it is located on the path `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Distribution\apache-maven-3.5.4\conf\Settings.xml`

Depending on the Settings.xml the Local Repository gets automatically configured to the specified location.
[image: Click here for screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I found that even after following all the steps above, I was still getting errors saying that my Maven dependencies (i.e. pom.xml) were pointing to jar files that didn't exist.

Viewing the errors in the Problems tab, for some reason these were still pointing to the old location of my repository. This was probably because I'd changed the location of my Maven repository since creating the workspace and project.

This can be easily solved by deleting the project from the Eclipse workspace, and re-adding it again through Package Explorer -> R/Click -> Import... -> Existing Projects.

Answer (score -2):

Here is `settings.xml` -->  `C:\maven\conf\settings.xml`