# Cannot search for a dependency in local repostory

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, maven-2

I recently installed plugin `m2e` - Maven integration into Eclipse. I created a `Maven` project, a simple `pom.xml` and added a local repository URL in it. However, when I go to `Dependency` section of `pom.xml` in Eclipse, click on `Add`, and try to search for a library, the results are from default Maven repository and not from local repository.

How do I make `m2e` plugin search in the local repository while searching for and adding a dependency.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235374/how-to-change-maven-local-repository-in-eclipse ?

Comment: @drvdijk: Yes I did before I posted the question. The local repository I talked about is not in a directory in my system, it is hosted on a company server. I know the URL and put that in pom.xml (under proper <repository> tags). The link you posted has a question which explains how to add a local directory as a repository not a repository sitting somewhere within the network. I know that I can access the repository because I can add dependencies by typing out their groupId and artifectId. It's just that when I search for them, I get results from default repository. Care to explain downvote?

Comment: The downvote wasn't mine, I question it too. Actually, I'm upvoting it to 0 right now :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment you provided, I'm going to suggest adding the repository to your [local maven settings file](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories), generally located at `~/.m2/settings.xml`. That way, the plugin should look in that repository as well.

Comment: There is no such `settings.xml` in my .m2 directory. Is a simple, default not created at the installation time?

Comment: Nope it isn't, you have to create it yourself (but it can be very short).

Answer (score 0):

According to the M2E FAQ, the [repository must provide an index](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_FAQ#How_Search_Works). Can you verify that yours does have an index? And you might want to open the Maven repositories view in Eclipse, check that your repository is listed there and play with the index options given in the context menu of the repository entries. I've never understood those options, but they might be related to this.