# Maven Dependencies Location

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm using Eclipse Luna and having trouble with a imported third party Maven project.  In *Maven Dependencies* the project has several jars, but the project is insisting they are to be found in C:\Users\username.m2\repository when they're not.

How do I tell it they are not there but in E:\java\jars?

I tried changing *Native Library Locations* but that didn't work, and there is nothing in the **pom** file that says which folder location to use.  All attempts to get the *classpath* to work have failed (probably due to my newness to this environment).

Comment: Why aren't the libraries in your repo? That's where maven dependencies *should* be.

Comment: Are you looking for this? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235374/how-to-change-maven-local-repository-in-eclipse

Comment: The Maven way is to have a local repository at ~/.m2/repository. Why do you want to change it? You could configure Maven to have another location for that local repository, but that affects all Maven builds on your machine.

Comment: @DaveNewton that's bs... one does not version dependencies when using maven. That'd defeat about two thirds of the reasons for using maven in the first place.

Comment: @Vogel612 Maven dependencies go in the repo. Dependency *resolution* is Maven's job, the dependencies themselves live in the repo.

Comment: @DaveNewton whoops. wrong "repo". Sorry, I was at VCS-repo there :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include your resource in your `pom.xml` as follows:

```
<project>
 <build>
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>[your folder here]</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
 </build>
</project>
```

Alternatively, you can add your 3rd Party JARs as a repository, like so:

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
       <id>lib_id</id>
       <url>file://your_path_to_lib/lib</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

Resources:

- [Specifying resource directories](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html).
- [Guides to installing 3rd Party JARs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).
- [Introduction to Repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html).
- [Related SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path).

Comment: Many thanks to all, and I've learnt something here.  That Maven uses a centralized repoitory for all Jars no matter where they come from.  It's something I didn't understand, I did say I was new to the environment. Anyway I've marked this answer as it addresses my question and works nicely.  best regards for the fextive season.