# Maven Eclipse downloading jar from central repository

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, m2eclipse

When I run mvn eclipse:eclipse against my project the dependencies are downloading from maven central repository http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.0/maven-site-plugin-3.0.pom. In the settings.xml file I'm pointing to the local repository c:\maven\repo to download the jar files from.But,  When I do the mvn clean install the jars are downloading from the local repository.

Not sure why the with mvn eclipse:eclipse it's always pointing to Maven central repository. Any idea, how I can get the mvn eclipse:eclipse point to local repository and download it from there.

Comment: You can find the answer here. [How to change Maven local repository in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235374/how-to-change-maven-local-repository-in-eclipse)

Comment: Just a hint for investigations: When you run mvn command with -X option, you will see the settings.xml which is used in real. To be sure that maven uses the configuration you expect.

Comment: Note that the eclipse:eclipse goal is no longer supported: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/